# Move row of data based on timestamp

Tags: timestamp, google-sheets

I'm trying to set up a script with no luck.

I want to move rows of data from "CC-COPPELL" to "Archive" when col 9 shows a value of <=Today().

Basically just move the stuff from yesterday to the archive if it was been completed. (I can't make a drop down menu to have it moved on a value such as "Yes" or "No" because the data needs to be readily available through the current day.)

Col 9 is an automatic timestamp based on a value entered on Col 8 if that helps.

I've searched and searched for a possible script that I can edit but alas I can't seem to find anything other that moving the data based upon an exact value.

Here is a sample Sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J-LOiqjcbPyqxffUp47pyXXIEr9kY0szTB8ciKmkEU0/edit?usp=sharing

I know you guys don't normally want people asking for scripts to be written but it's still a little beyond me as to writing one from scratch myself.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works for you ?

```
function onOpen() {
SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('Custom Menu')
    .addItem('Move Rows', 'moveRows')
    .addToUi();
}

function moveRows() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var s = ss.getSheetByName("CC-COPPELL");
var target = ss.getSheetByName("Archive");
var today = new Date().getTime()
var val = filterArray(s.getDataRange()
    .getValues());
for (var len = val.length - 1, i = len; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (val[i][8].getTime() < today) {
        target.appendRow(val[i])
        s.deleteRow(i + 2)
        }
    }
}

function filterArray(array) {
var filteredArray = [];
array.forEach(function (r) {
    if (r[8] !== '') {
        filteredArray.push(r);
    }
});
return filteredArray;
}
```